# Read data from csv flat file and add new data into the file

Tags: javascript, sapui5, hana

I am trying to read data from flat file (`csv` separated by ;).
For example this `csv` file has 4 columns. I want to add a 5th column to the flat file based on some calculation on the 4th column.

Once i get this, i will be uploading the flat file data to the `HANA` database table.

I have figured out reading the data from the flat file and uploading to the database using `SAPUI5`.
Is there anyway i can achieve the 5th column on the client side using `javascript`?

Comment: You cannot write to files using Javascript. However, why do you want your data in a file format?? Why not simply use OData to post to HANA?

Comment: well, i am not trying to write but want to add data to another column on the database calculated on the basis of data provided using flat file.

Comment: SAPUI5 is a pure frontend framework. You cannot use it to write to any database without a server.

Comment: Is there a way I can read the data from the flat file, do some calculations and a new data column, create a new temp file and update that on the DB table.

Comment: You can do that, if the mentioned file is delivered with your UI application. CSV processing must be done manually, however it's not a big challenge.

Comment: the file is selected by the user at the Browse event. how can CSV processing be done? can you give me some links ?or guide me ?